# Fixed redundancy in one-hot encoding but still having error when trying to invert it

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding, redundancy

I'm doing one-hot encoding and using ̂ =(()^−1) *  to estimate theta. I was getting an error because of redundancies so I decided to drop the columns that have redundancies.

This is prior to dropping columns:

[image]
This is my code for it as I try to drop the columns that have redundancies:

```
 def one_hot_encode_revised(data):
        
        all_columns = data.columns
    
        records = data[all_columns].to_dict(orient='records')
        encoder = DictVectorizer(sparse=False)
        encoded_X = encoder.fit_transform(records)
        df = pd.DataFrame(data=encoded_X, columns=encoder.feature_names_)
        
        return df.drop(['day=Fri', 'sex=Male', 'smoker=No', 'time=Dinner'], axis =1)
one_hot_X_revised = one_hot_encode_revised(X)
```

which outputs this:
[image]

Then, I use this function to estimate theta from the above equation:

```
def get_analytical_sol(X, y):
"""
Computes the analytical solution to our least squares problem

Parameters
-----------
X: a 2D dataframe of numeric features (one-hot encoded)
y: a 1D vector of tip amounts

Returns
-----------
The estimate for theta
"""
return np.linalg.inv(X.T * X) * (X.T * y)
```

to run this:

```
revised_analytical_thetas = get_analytical_sol(one_hot_X_revised, tips)
```

My error is : ValueError: Unable to coerce to DataFrame, shape must be (8, 244): given (252, 252)

For reference, tips is this:

[image]

Did I get rid of the redundancies correctly and if yes, why do I still have the error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in this line `return np.linalg.inv(X.T * X) * (X.T * y)`. What you want to do is a matrix multiplication. In pandas dataframes, the sign `*` is not used for matrix multiplication. You need to use `@` or the `dot()` method of the dataframe.